# Which positive continuous functions satisfy $F(x) = F(e^x)-F(e^{-x})$ for $x\geq 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, stochastic-processes, taylor-expansion, functional-equations

There is at least one such function. It is the cdf of the equilibrium probability distribution for the chaotic sequence $x(n+1) = |\log x(n)|$ with $x(1) = 2$. Its graph (approximation) is pictured below. I am interested in a series expansion for the density $f(x)$, which is the derivative of $F(x)$.

[image]

**Note**

I expect that if you start with a different seed, say $x(1) =3$, you end up with the same distribution, unless you pick up one of the very rare seeds (called *bad seed)* that results in a different $F$. The set of bad seeds has Lebesgue measure zero, but it is infinite and even dense. My intuition is based on the following: consider instead $x(n+1) = bx(n) - \lfloor bx(n) \rfloor$. The equilibrium distribution is uniform on $[0, 1]$ this time (if $b$ is an integer larger than 1) unless you pick up a bad seed. All rational numbers are bad seeds. Tons of other numbers are bad seeds. But the vast majority are good seeds. A good seed is equivalent to a normal number: its digits in base $b$ are evenly distributed. No one knows if $\pi, e, \log 2$ or $\sqrt{2}$ is a good seed. More on this in [my article on the theory of randomness](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/fascinating-new-results-in-the-theory-of-randomness) or [my book on organized chaos](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/fee-book-applied-stochastic-processes).

Similarly, in our context here, proving that $x(1) = 2$ is a good seed is a very hard problem, and possibly un-provable. Yet plenty of evidence makes you believe that it is a good seed. Some sequences such as $x(n+1) = b+x(n) - \lfloor b + x(n)\rfloor$ do not have bad seeds if $b$ is irrational. The logistic map $x(n+1) = 4x(n)\cdot (1-x(n))$ has plenty of bad seeds. In our example $x(1) = 0.567143...$ is a bad seed because $x(2) = x(1)$ and thus $x(n) = x(1)$ for all $n$.

Comment: By the definition the function has to be odd and increasing. Neither of these properties holds for the graph.

Comment: Still $F(0)=1$ in this... Shouldn't $F(0)=0$ instead?

Comment: OK, everything is fixed now. The functional relationship is back to what it was when I first posted it, and I changed the chart. The new chart, as well as the new $F$ now represents the cdf, not the density as previously stated. Sorry for the mix-up.

Comment: The density $f(x)$ satisfies $f(x) = e^x f(e^x) + e^{-x}f(e^{-x})$.

Comment: The functional equation alone is not very informative. You can define $F(x)$ on $[0,1]$ in any way you want (just keeping $F(0)=0$), after which it extends in a unique way to the rest of the positive ray.

Comment: @fedja However $F(\infty)=1$. I don't think all solutions to the above functional equation satisfy that,  and if that is true, this condition seems to impose conditions on the way one constructs the $(0,1]$ interval.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg If we first ensure $F(\infty)$ is finite, we can scale.

Comment: I added a note in my question (below the picture) that could help clarify this discussion.

Comment: "There is at least one such function." You mean a function with continuous non-negative derivative? That would be great to know. Do you have a proof?

Comment: @Fedja: yes, with continuous non-negative derivative. It is a solution (fixed point) $F$ to the stochastic integral equation $P_F[ X < x] = P_F[  |\log  X| < x ]$. Approximations, converging to the solution, can be built.

Comment: Interesting. What is your way to prove the convergence of the approximations?

Comment: @Fedja: Build a sequence $F_n$ (for instance, polynomial of degree $n$), choose $F_n$ so that it minimizes the error $E(n) =\int_0^\infty [F_n(x) - F_n(\exp (x)) + F_n(\exp(-x))]^2 dx$ and show (that's the difficult part, I haven't solved it) that $E(n)\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: "show (that's the difficult part, I haven't solved it) " Yeah, I "haven't solved" it either. Moreover, I do not even know how to proceed from $E_n\to 0$ to the convergence of $F_n$ themselves. OK, let me think :-)

Comment: @TM Gallagher, Sorry to drag you into this, but I've stumbled upon your profile and since you are an expert in fixed point theorems, I wondered if you could take a look at this fixed point problem. Particularly if the iteration method I describe could be shown to converge to a unique cumulative distribution. I've tried a bit with a Lévy metric, hoping to apply the Banach fixed point theorem, but it seems the operator $T$ is not a contraction mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take as a seed the function $F_0(x)=\exp(-\exp(-x))-\exp(-\exp(x))$ and plug it into the iteration

$$F_{n+1}(x) = F_n(\exp(x))-F_n(\exp(-x))$$

you can generate ever better approximations to the distribution. After only two iterations I got this result:

[image: Cumulative distibution]

[image: Density]

You can also apply the trick directly on the density.

[See also my answer to this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2701525/solving-fx-fex-f-ex/2707354#2707354)

Comment: Are you sure that you'll get the same distribution? As I said, the fixed points are many.

Comment: If you mean sure as in having a proof: no. But I'm pretty sure this does give the right distribution yes.

Comment: Why? (I'm really curious: if you have a good answer to this question, we may discern some extra property of $F$ that, together with the functional equation will allow us to determine it uniquely)

Comment: See my reply to the question I linked to in my answer. I explain how I came with the idea for using this specific seed and not another one.

Comment: It sounds like my recursion is known as the logarithmic map.

Comment: If you use a seed $x(1)$ such that (say) $x(500) = x(1)$ you will get a different distribution $F$, but in that case it is a discrete distribution (thus not continuous).

Comment: @fedja, I wonder if it's sufficient for the seed to have the properties of a cumulative distribution, i.e. having $F(0)=0$, $F(\infty)=1$ and being monotonously increasing, to guarantee convergence to the unique distribution that is related to the logarithmic map?

Comment: We could use the Banach fixed point theorem to prove the existence of a unique fixed point. We have to show that the space of cumulative distributions is a complete metric space under some suitable metric, and that the map $T$ such that $T(F)(x) = F(e^x)-F(e^{-x})$ is a contraction mapping for that metric.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Interesting thoughts. Applied to a different sequence, namely $x(n+1) = bx(n) - \lfloor bx(n)\rfloor$ whose equilibrium (for a good seed) is the uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$ proving that the seed $\pi$ leads to that solution would imply that the digits of $\pi$ are uniformly distributed in base $b$. This is one of the most challenging unsolved mathematical problems of all times.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess I'm too optimistic then about being able to apply Banach's fixed point theorem, because if it was straightforwardly applicable, then it would have been applied to the case of a distribution concentrated on $\pi$. That said, it's immediately obvious that it cannot work for any discrete distribution for the logarithmic map either. Indeed, take the discrete distribution concentrated on the bad seed $0.567143\ldots$. This is already a fixed point of the iteration on the distributional level.

Comment: The only hope of a Banach fixed point theorem approach would be on a restricted class of distributions. Probably excluding all discrete distributions, probably even more restricted than that.

Comment: Actually, it's pretty certain that all discrete distributions have to be excluded since they either are already fixed points, either never converge, either are cyclic points. Plus you get that $T$ sometimes maps a right-continuous function to a left-continuous. Which is outside of the space of distributions if we play the game strictly. So, only continuous distributions should be allowed.

Comment: And there is also an entire class of functions that can be constructed from extending an arbitrary continuous function on the interval $[0,1]$ using $F(x)=F(\log(x))+F(1/x)$ which will lead to a fixed point of $T$, as fedja pointed out previously.